# Infragistics grid : row overlapping

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using Infragistics ultrawingrid v16.1 in windows application. Below are Row style properties of grid. each cell in row has 3 to 4 lines of data. But it is showing only first line. In below screenshot, first line data is overlapped. I'm expecting the data shown as in second row. Please let me know how to show entire data of a cell. Thanks in advance.

```
this.grd1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectors = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.False;
this.grd1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSizing = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowSizing.AutoFree;
this.grd1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSizingArea = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowSizingArea.EntireRow;
this.grd1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSizingAutoMaxLines = 5;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should tell the grid that the cells are multiline cells. To do so set [CellMultiLine](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragridcolumn~cellmultiline) to true like this:

```
this.grd1.DisplayLayout.Override.CellMultiLine = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
```

Here is and sample in Infragistics online documentation about this property - "[Displaying Multi-Line Cells](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/wingrid-displaying-multi-line-cells)"

Comment: I've added this line in imports 'using Infragistics.Win;' and added your line, still it is not showing all lines

Comment: Where did  you add all this code? To make it work try to add in in InitializeLayout event handler. Also you may remove/comment RowSizingAutoMaxLines = 5, to be sure all the lines in the cell will be shown.

Comment: You can leave your settings as is, and hook to the InitializeLayout event, (like wnvko said), by double clicking over the UltraGrid in Design time, and use there the EventArgs to set the CellMultiLine to True like: 

        private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Layout.Override.CellMultiLine = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can leave your settings as is, and hook to the InitializeLayout event, (like wnvko said), by double clicking over the UltraGrid in Design time, and use there the EventArgs to set the CellMultiLine to True like:

```
    private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
       e.Layout.Override.CellMultiLine = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add height to your row below is property to add max height to row

`this.grd1.DisplayLayout.Override.MaxRowHeight = 100;`

set your required height

Comment: After adding above line, I'm getting this error, 'UltraGridOverride' does not contain a definition for 'MaxRowHeight' and no extension method 'MaxRowHeight' accepting a first argument of type 'UltraGridOverride' could be found

Comment: There is no MaxRowHeight property under Override. There is DefaultRowHeight, but it won't help here, look at my comment on the above post, to achieve what you are looking for, using CellMultiLine property.